# Load jpg then on top of it write some text at a 90 degree angle. then convert to pdf?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

Using the pdfsharp.net library -- Im trying to load a big background jpg then on top of it write some text at a 90 degree angle. then save as a pdf

Why does my c# code below not work.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using PdfSharp;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;


namespace test
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PdfDocument myDoc = new PdfDocument();
            PdfPage myPage = myDoc.AddPage();
            myPage.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.A4;

            XGraphics g = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(myPage);
            XImage image = XImage.FromFile(@"myjpg.jpg");
            g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, myPage.Width, myPage.Height);


            XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);
            g.RotateAtTransform(90,new XPoint(0,0));
            g.DrawString("test text!", font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 0, 200, 50), XStringFormats.Center);

            myDoc.Save(@"test.pdf");
            Process.Start(@"test.pdf");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What isn't working about it? Are you getting errors/exceptions? If you want a good answer, please provide us with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: your rotating at (0,0) - maybe you're rotating the text out of the page. Just presuming you see the picture but not the text.
See here for a working sample that uses rotation:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/XForms-sample.ashx

Center of rotation is not (0,0) in the sample.

If my guess is wrong, please provide more information what your code does.